# How to use only create without FactoryGirl.create

Tags: ruby, rspec, factory-bot

How I can use only `create` without `FactoryGirl`?

I have a lot of place where I call `FactoryGirl.create`.

Answer (score 2):

```
# rails_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  #...
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

Comment: Where I need to place this code? At the beginning of the file?

Comment: @PeterPenzov I noticed you rarely accept the answer to your questions. I suggest you to go over your questions and accept the answers to those, which indeed got answered and solved.